# Why Won't My Program Read A File Into An Array Correctly?

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I'm trying to read a sudoku board into a character array and output it using a classes and functions, but all I get is a bunch of random characters. In my program, I am trying to prompt the user for a level and then open a random sudoku file of that level. I have 40 files, 10 for each of 4 levels.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "time.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class Open {
protected:
    int fileNum = 0;
    int level = 0;
    string VeryEasy[10], Easy[10], Medium[10], Hard[10];
    ifstream fin;

public:
    void promptLevel() {
        cout << "Anytime throughout the game, Enter N for new game, Q to 
quit, and A to see your average score" << endl;
        cout << "Which would you like to play? Enter 1 for Very Easy, 2 for 
Easy, 3 for Medium, and 4 for Hard" << endl;
        cin >> level;
    }
    void setFiles() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            VeryEasy[i] = "VeryEasy" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
            Easy[i] = "Easy" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
            Medium[i] = "Medium" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
            Hard[i] = "Hard" + to_string(i) + ".txt";
        }
    }
    void openFile() {
        fileNum = rand() % 10;
        if (level == 1) fin.open(VeryEasy[fileNum]);
        else if (level == 2) fin.open(Easy[fileNum]);
        else if (level == 3) fin.open(Medium[fileNum]);
        else if (level == 4) fin.open(Hard[fileNum]);
        if (!fin.is_open()) {
            cout << "Failure" << endl;
        }
    }
};
class Board : public Open {
private:
    char boardChar[9][9];
public:
    void readBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                fin.get(boardChar[i][j]);
                cout << boardChar[i][j];
            }
            fin.ignore();
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
};
int main() {
    Open O1;
    Board B1;
    O1.setFiles();
    O1.promptLevel();
    B1.openFile();
    B1.readBoard();

    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't work when I call these functions, but it does work when I create the board in the main function without all the other stuff.
It's supposed to look something like this:

```
  58     
18 97    
 67  4 5 
8   4  9 
5 2   3 1
 7  1   5
 5 4  76 
    26 84
     81
```

It would be awesome if you guys could help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your main function?

Comment: The `for loop` in `openFile` is unnecssary. Jusst pointing out

Comment: How doesn't it work? Please describe in detail, as it is difficult to tell where you might be going wrong. (Also, the `for (int j` loop in `readBoard()` should loop to `9`, not `10`. Furthermore, your sample output is bizarre, quite frankly.)

Comment: In the `readBoard` function `i` goes to 9, but `j` goes to 10. That doesn't match the size of the board.

Comment: Yeah I changed j to 9, but it still didn't work. I tried just opening a file directly using the file name and it worked, but as soon as I use the if statements or the array while opening the file, the file doesn't open. I'll edit my code above to show you guys what I have right now.